# Suppose $T$ is a linear operator $(V,V)$, and $T^2=T$. Does this means it is the identity operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

Since we're saying $T^2=T$, isn't $T$ a square root of itself? So that would only happen if $T=I$, correct?

Another thing I tried is, for $u$, $v$ in $V$, where $Tu=v, TTu=Tu \to T(v)=v  \to T=I$

is this correct?

Comment: Think about projections.

Comment: Operators with this property are in fact called [projection operators](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: For your first method: yes, assuming $T^2 = T$, we might also be able to say $T = \sqrt{T}$ if we defined $\sqrt{T}$ appropriately. Setting aside the issues with the square root of an operator, what additional information would this give us, anyway?

Comment: For your second method: here, you "divide" both sides by $T$, which assumes that $T$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Both zero and the identity satisfy this. More generally, any linear operator which is diagonalizable and has only $1$s,  and $0$s as eigenvalues satisfies this equation.

So the answer is no.

Comment: do you mean if all the entries in the diagonal are 0 (or all the entries are 1) or do you mean they are a mix of 1's and 0's?

Comment: a mix of 1s and 0s will do it